# Получение разницы между массивами

Tags: javascript, массивы

Решаю задачи с codewars. Необходимо получить разницу массивов а - b. В первом случае не отрабатывает  filter с данными ниже аргументами.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    arr = a.filter(item => item !== b[i]);
  }  
  return arr;
  }

console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2, 2], []));
```

Во втором случае со splice.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            a.splice(i, 1);
        }     
      }
    }
    return a;    
  }
 
 console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2, 2], [2]));
```

Хорошо что есть тесты, но уже крыша едет)) Помогите решить, пожалуйста!

Comment: А что значит *разницу массивов*? Хорошо бы привести пример входящих и исходящих данных.

Comment: `function arrayDiff(a, b) {    
    return a.filter(item => !b.includes(item));
}` ??  только дубли убрать

Comment: Как все просто! Спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае вы запускаете цикл, и на каждой итерации перезаписываете результат отработки фильтра, в итоге получаете значение с последней итерации.
Во втором вы почему то хотите вернуть переменную 'a', но по вашему коду предполагаю, что хотите вырезать переменную и вставить ее в массив arr, который задекларировали ранее?

Вот измененное решение вашего первого варианта

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    let arr = a;
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
    arr = arr.filter(item => item !== b[i]);
  }  
  return arr;
  }

console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2, 2], []));
```

Comment: Спасибо! В первом случае согласен, что перезаписывание результата в цикле так себе, но проблема там с пустым массивом. Во втором случае не убрал arr из предыдущего примера, но это ничего не решает.

Comment: дописал в ответе изменения к вашему первому варианту, чтоб работало сравнение

Comment: Спасибо! А то я уже и условия писал, а надо было просто присвоить arr = a. Круто, спасибо!